# SQLZOO - select from world tutorial #13

Tags: mysql, sql

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial#All_the_vowels

Equatorial Guinea and Dominican Republic have all of the vowels (a e i o u) in the name. They don't count because they have more than one word in the name.

Find the country that has all the vowels and no spaces in its name.
You can use the phrase name NOT LIKE '%a%' to exclude characters from your results.

The query shown misses countries like Bahamas and Belarus because they contain at least one 'a'

I thought I could do this with more of a brute force method of nesting many OR statements but that didn't work and I'm not sure how to exclude a space from showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to exclude the space

```
AND NOT LIKE '% %'
```

Answer (score 16):

You want *all* of the vowels in the word, so you need to use `AND`, not `OR`.

Also, to exclude something from the reply, you can use `NOT LIKE`. This exclusion condition counts in addition to all the vowel-conditions, so it too needs to be linked with AND.

If you can't solve it yourself, move your cursor over this block to see a valid solution:

```
SELECT name
FROM world
WHERE name LIKE '%A%'
AND name LIKE '%E%'
AND name LIKE '%I%'
AND name LIKE '%O%'
AND name LIKE '%U%'
AND name LIKE '%a%'
AND name LIKE '%e%'
AND name LIKE '%i%'
AND name LIKE '%o%'
AND name LIKE '%u%'
AND name NOT LIKE '% %'
```

(check [this answer's sourcecode](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42773255/edit) for a properly formatted solution)

Comment: thanks! that's what i thought to do, but some reason it doesn't like that syntax.

Comment: @madman Strange. It works perfectly for me. Are you sure you have set "SQL Engine: MySQL" in the upper right corner of the webpage? If that doesn't help, please post the EXACT error message you receive.

Comment: I don't think capitals check are needed here.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name FROM world 
WHERE name LIKE '%a%'
AND name LIKE '%e%'
AND name LIKE '%i%'
AND name LIKE '%o%'
AND name LIKE '%u%'
AND name NOT LIKE '% %'
```

- Use AND, not OR since you need all the vowels, not either one of them.
- '%a%' denotes any combination of strings that has character 'a' in it. So you need to do it for all the vowels.
- NOT LIKE '% %' means we don't need any spaces in our strings. This means it excludes countries that have more than one word in their names.
- The correct answer is **Mozambique**. There is only one name that meets this criteria.
- If you delete the last line of the code, **AND name NOT LIKE '% %'**, you will get **Democratic Republic of Congo, 
  Equatorial Guinea,
  Mozambique,
  Dominican Republic** as answers. Try it ! Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE name LIKE '%a%' AND 
name  LIKE '%e%' AND 
name  LIKE '%i%' AND 
name  LIKE '%o%' AND 
name  LIKE '%u%' AND 
name NOT LIKE '% %'
```

Comment: Please add an explanation around your code only answer. Code only answers are often downvoted and may be deleted. Thanks